# How can I clear normal mode command count in mappings?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, count

I have a mapping like this:

```
noremap <expr> zj FindNext()
```

`FindNext` will calculate which line to go, and return something like `10G`.

This works without a count, but with a count the line number becomes incorrect. For example, if the count is `2`, `10G` will become `210G`. So I'm looking for a way to erase the count.

It is easy with `:<C-U>execute 'normal! ' . FindNext()<CR>` mapping, but it doesn't work in visual mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make it work in Visual mode by using Normal mode but re-creating the visual selection first with the `gv` command.

`:<C-u>execute 'normal! gv' . FindNext()<CR>`

And then use the mapping specific to Visual and Select modes (`:vnoremap`
, `:xnoremap`, `:snoremap`). See `:help mapmode-x`.

---

You didn't supply much information on what your function does, so I'm not sure it this helps. I tried this simple function and mappings

```
function! Bar()
    echo "the count was " . v:count1
endfunction

noremap foo :<C-u>call Bar()<cr>
xnoremap foo :<C-u>call Bar()<cr>
```

The result is correct both in Normal and Visual modes. For example `10foo` results in "the count was 10" in either mode.

But if you use the mappings bellow (which execute 2 commands one after another) it doesn't work anymore. `2foo` always results in "the count was 1".

```
noremap foo :<C-u>exec 'normal! j ' <bar> call Bar()<cr>
xnoremap foo :<C-u>exec 'normal! gv j ' <bar> call Bar()<cr>
```

My conclusion from this is that the first command resets `v:count1`.

So I tried

```
function! Bar()
    let x = v:count1
    normal! j
    echo "the count was " . x
endfunction

noremap foo :<C-u>call Bar()<cr>
xnoremap foo :<C-u>call Bar()<cr>
```

and it works again. Note that `v:count1` has to be saved before the `normal!` is executed. Otherwise its value will be lost.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but do you know how to get the count in visual mode? v:count1 doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @yyt16384, I edited my answer.

Comment: I think I get the point: every normal mode command resets v:count1, so the count needs to be saved before :normal.